# Цветная иконка в уведомлениях Notification

Tags: android

Мучаюсь вопросом, как все же сделать в smallicon цветную картинку? Другие приложения, типа вконтакте, вайбер и другие выводят цветную иконку в уведомления, а как это сделать не понятно, иконка выводится черно-белая.

Готовлю уведомления таким образом:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("текст")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)

            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_notification))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("текст"))
            .setContentText("текст")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: не помню точно с какой версии андроида, но гугл запретили цветные картинки в статусбаре

Comment: Да? почему тогда другие приложения популярные спокойно делают цветные? И главное как?)

Comment: ну это только у вас, скорее всего старая версия андроида. уже посмотрел. начиная с 5.0 иконки одного цвета (белые/темные). либо это фишки оболочки, если у вас какой-то мейзу/сяоми

Comment: Да, похоже я погорячился, иконки цветные только на не стандартных статус барах, типа MIUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void addNotification(String ss) {
    String ssBigText = ss;
    //айди нотификации
    inc++;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    //параметры отображения нотификации
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Внимание")
            .setContentTitle("Не забудьте")
            .setContentText(ss)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notify) // картинка *.png должна быть одного цвета
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))// это большой значок многоцветный
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_alpha100)); // даём прозрачность на бэкграунд
    }

    Notification mNotify = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mNotify = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder).bigText(ssBigText).build();
    }else{
        mNotify = builder.getNotification();
    }

    final NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotify != null) {
        mNotify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    }

    Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Log.e("AMBR.addNotification", "time rings on: "+ today.getTime());
    mNM.notify(inc, mNotify);

}
```

Начиная с android 5 версии, маленький значок в статус-баре может быть 1 или 2 цветов. Как дела обстоят с версией выше 5, не знаю.

Тот же watsapp или dolphin browser имеют 2 цвета. Я ставил значок и за ним цвет фона. Вроде как, можно векторно нарисовать любую фигуру и сделать её фоном.

Если я в чём-то ошибся, поправьте пожалуйста